# after migrating kvm virtual machine with Centos7 to LXD container, the only process that starts at boot is systemd (/sbin/init)

Tags: systemd, boot, lxd, dbus

the title pretty much describes it all. After starting the container the only running process is `/sbin/init` which is a link to `systemd`. No syslog, empty journalctl, `lxc-start` with console attached gives nothing, no D-BUS - so all systemd control commands fail.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot in this situation?

Comment: Where does lxc redirect the "console" output (i.e. /dev/console) of the container? Does systemd at least mount /run within the container? (Without D-Bus, you would normally still have a "direct" systemd control socket under /run/systemd.)

Comment: Everything was properly mounted but the only file under /run/systemd was /run/systemd/container. I've found the source of the problem, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot the start of `systemd` try:

```
lxc stop --force centos7
lxc config set centos7 raw.lxc 'lxc.init.cmd = /bin/bash'
lxc start centos7 --console
To detach from the console, press: <ctrl>+a q

[root@centos7 /]# exec /sbin/init
```

I got:

```
Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Operation not permitted
systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Detected virtualization lxc.
Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to CentOS Linux 7 (Core)!

Set hostname to <opennms.man.szczecin.pl>.
Cannot determine cgroup we are running in: No such file or directory
Failed to allocate manager object: No such file or directory
[!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object, freezing.
```

And according to this discussion: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/solved-not-a-bug-strange-cgroups-bug-on-ubuntu-21-10/13341
it's the problem with *cgroups* incompatibility (1 vs 2).

**TL;DR**: Centos7's systemd requires *cgroups* 1 and my host (Ubuntu 22.04) provides only *cgroups* 2.